# Add a Column to the "Used By" Section of a Discussion Board in Classic SP

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, discussion-board

I have created a discussion board in classic SharePoint. By default, there are three things you can choose when creating a new discussion: Subject, Body, and selecting whether or not your discussion is a Question. I wish to add one more selection to this called "Category", where users can categorize the type of question they have (i.e. Math, Science, etc).

I added a column called "Question Category" as you can see below. However, I can't figure out how to include this column in the "Used in" section on the right so that it appears as an option when someone is making a discussion post. Could not find anything online that could help. How do I do this?

[image: Columns in a discussion board]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the new column "`Question Category`" to the Content-Type, not the list columns!